# Footprint of a redis server

Tags: memory, embedded, redis

I'm new to Redis. I want to get an idea of how heavy a redis instance in terms of it's memory footprint (without considering the actual data that is being stored in memory)? It there a "lite" version of Redis ? Or are there other options that will work in this environment ?

Comment: Seems easy enough to install, measure, add data, measure etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very small. In the pre-sharding section of the partitioning information page, it states that a "spare" instance uses about 1MB of RAM. http://redis.io/topics/partitioning